# Daylight saving option on Linux servers

Tags: timezone, ntp

My CentOS server is not updating showing correct time. I have set

```
$ ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/London  /etc/localtime
```

Still I am on GMT.

I do see the following entries in `/etc/sysconfig/clock`:

```
$cat /etc/sysconfig/clock
ZONE="Europe/London"
UTC=true
ARC=false
```

Still it is not showing correct time.

NTP is running on this server:

```
$ ntpq -p
remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
+         IP Address      3 u   42 1024  377    0.476   63.077   0.001
*         IP Address      3 u   53 1024  377    1.183   30.425   0.001
```

The ntp servers have the correct time. These are Windows Domain Controllers.

I have checked out the answer from here https://serverfault.com/questions/267629/configure-centos-with-ntp but that hasn't helped on this case.

Any ideas?

Comment: When you say "Still I am on GMT", what does that mean? You haven't shown an example of the problem. I suspect you have some processes with the old `TZ` variable left in their environment, but you haven't said which process is misbehaving so I can't say how you should fix it.

Comment: What I mean by "Still I am on GMT", is the server is one hour behind. I need to set the server on BST. BST is 1 hour ahead of Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)

Comment: What is your evidence? What command are you running to determine that "the server is one hour behind"?

Comment: The date command shows this output. 
Fri Jun 28 09:16:28 GMT 2013

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere. Do you have a `TZ` variable? `echo TZ=$TZ ; date`

Comment: no TZ variable is set. Command echo TZ=$TZ ; date shows:
TZ=
Fri Jun 28 09:22:13 GMT 2013

Comment: That eliminates my first guess. Next up: do some investigation. `strace date 2>&1 | grep localtime` ; `file -L /etc/localtime`

Comment: open("/etc/localtime", O_RDONLY)        = 3
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=118, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=118, ...}) = 0
/etc/localtime: timezone data

Comment: `st_size=118` is a sign that your `/etc/localtime` is GMT. The `Europe/London` file should be bigger than that. Your `ln -s` must have failed. Check it with `ls -l /etc/localtime`

Comment: Is there any chance that tzdata is not updated?            $ ls -l /etc/localtime
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 33 Jun 28 08:16 /etc/localtime -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/London

Comment: and what does `ntpdate <ip of ntp server>` returns?

Comment: It's not receiving correct time from ntp server           $ ntpdate 10.10.4.10
28 Jun 14:05:35 ntpdate[27739]: the NTP socket is in use, exiting

Comment: I have recently come across to the opinion that it's better to keep server's zone to UTC.  It is better to represent different time zone on the application that the user is interacting directly with.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Separate out the problem: is it a Timezone misconfiguration, or a time configuration? You can use a couple of tools, date and zdump to determine this.

If date reports the correct UTC time, then you know the problem exists in the timezone setting, rather than in the internal time setting.

```
$ date --utc
Fri Jun 28 14:02:43 UTC 2013
$ date
Fri Jun 28 10:02:45 EDT 2013
```

zdump will print the current time (pulled from the internal UTC time) in the zone for each timezone specified

```
$ zdump /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/London /usr/share/zoneinfo/GMT
/usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/London  Tue Jun 28 15:02:49 2013 BST
/usr/share/zoneinfo/GMT            Tue Jun 28 14:02:49 2013 GMT
```

If the Europe/London zoneinfo file produces the same time as the GMT zoneinfo file, then either the contents of Europe/London or GMT are incorrect. I'd be surprised if this is the case, but if so, look to either reinstall the file from rpm, or otherwise correct it.  I believe there are programs available to read and output the zoneinfo contents, but don't know them as I just wrote my own that does it.

If you reach the case that the internal UTC time is correct, and the zoneinfo file is correct, but date still reports GMT, then the setting for localtime is incorrect or stale. `man tzset` will tell you more than you want to know on how the local time conversion happens, but do an `env` and look at the settings for environment variables TZ, TZDIR. Finally compare the localtime config file with the desired setting: with `cmp /etc/localtime /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/London`

Comment: zdump /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/London /usr/share/zoneinfo/GMT showed both Europe/London and GMT were showing same data which was wrong. I reinstalled tzdata rpm package and that has corrected it. Many thanks @Richard Perrin